# Can JSF Validators be maliciously circumvented?

Tags: validation, jsf, seam

Faces validators can provide a nicer UI experience for form field validation than returning messages from the action after form submission.  But do I need the belt and braces approach of also validating in the action on form submit?  I can't find a definitive answer on how possible it is to maliciously submit the form bypassing faces validators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF validators run on the server side, not on the client side. They can in no way be bypassed. You should not need to re-validate the whole bunch in the action method. Even more, doing per-field validation in action method instead of in a validator is considered poor practice.